# Bug in coercion of large vectors?

Tags: r, vector, stack-overflow, coercion

I just installed R version 3.5.0 and according to [this article on Revolution Analytics](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2018/04/r-350.html) there is a [new internal representation of vectors](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/09/altrep-preview.html).

When I do the following I either get no result at all (see the following example) or the whole computer freezes for good:

```
> x <- 1:1e9
> c(x, "a")
>
```

So it seems that there is some routine missing which catches an overflow error in such cases (or at least gives a warning).

**My question**
Is this a reproducible bug?

Comment: What if you do this with a smaller x vector?

Comment: @docendodiscimus: it works ok

Comment: I'm really just guessing here but based on the linked description ("WIth ALTREP, a sequence like this is instead represented by just its start and end values, which takes up almost no memory at all.") I assume that initially x can be stored very efficiently by using start and end point, but as you concatenate "a", the whole integer vector has to be coerced to character and hence stored more traditionally - i.e. memory intensive - since I doubt that a character vector can be stored using start and end values.

Comment: @docendodiscimus: This is what I suspect but the resulting behaviour seems buggy in the above case.

Comment: Do you have enough ram? When I do this with an older R version on my 16 gb laptop, it also feels like frozen. But that's probably just a ram-issue, I guess.

Comment: @docendodiscimus: the freezing could be a ram issue, what worries me  though is that sometimes (after waiting for quite some time) I get *no* result at all (see example above). Not even a warning!

Comment: That sounds unusual indeed. Since I don't have 3.5.0 installed, I cannot run this test myself to reproduce it.

Comment: Working on my dinosaur (x86, thus limited memory access), I get a memory related error. `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.7Gb`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same sequence of statements causes R to (apparently) hang in 3.4.x as well. You are creating a character object that requires at least 8Gb of RAM, which may take a while if it completes at all.

On R 3.4.3 I get the message "Error: cannot allocate a vector of size 7.5Gb", which I expect. On R 3.5.0 the message is "cannot allocate a vector of size 128.0Mb". The size is incorrect: R 3.5.0 is still trying to create an 8Gb object here. But the wait and ultimate failure is not surprising.

Your statement does work as expected for smaller object sizes.

Comment: What worries me is that sometimes (after waiting for quite some time) I get no result at all (see example above). Not even a warning!

Comment: The size of allocation is not necessarily the size of the created object. It depends on the internal operations. I tested in R 3.5.0 on Windows 10, and I get "cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb" here. What OS are you running on and what's the output of `R.Version()$"svn rev"` ?